# Adding functionalities to the right border of an AdvanceDataGrid component

Tags: apache-flex

I'd like to add some functionalities to the right border of my ADG component to help the user resize and potentially do more stuff. Is there a skin for that border? For instance, how would you make it wider, or add a handle that perhaps animates when you hover over it?

thank you, yet again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no skin that allows you to do this. You have only two options:

1. Extend ADG and add the desired functionality.
2. Create a custom component that can contain an ADG and add additional components und functionality to your custom component.

Extending ADG is no fun at all. So, if possible I'd choose option 2. In MXML it could look something like this:

```
<ns1:MyAdvancedDataGridContainer>
    <ns1:dataGrid>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGrid ...>
            <!-- your columns and stuff like that -->
        </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
    </ns1:dataGrid>
</ns1>
```

`MyAdvancedDataGridContainer` would add all the fancy stuff you need without the need of changing and overriding lots of ADG's ugly code.